# Looking to mount Linux root dir to Windows drive letter

Tags: windows, linux, mount

I have a RH5 box and develop on Windows.  I'm looking to mount the root dir of the RH machine just for ease of integration and automatic deployment to the linux box.  I'm using WinSCP at the moment but that  (from what I can find) only opens a window, which isnt accessible from eclipse.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443732/how-do-i-mount-a-remote-linux-folder-in-windows-through-ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can easily share any path you want using [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) and mount it in Windows (Samba implements the Windows-native SMB/CIFS protocol, so you can mount it on Windows just like you'd mount any other drive from a remote WIndows PC).